# Making a AnimationQueue

Tags: wpf, queue, ellipse, wpf-animation, doubleanimation

I have been trying to make a Ellipse to follow a given trajectory with the DoubleAnimation class. So far not too good.

I made a custom class AnimationQueue :

```
    private class AnimationQueue
    {
        private List<DoubleAnimation> animation1 ;
        private DependencyProperty property1;
        private bool running1;
        private List<DoubleAnimation> animation2;
        private DependencyProperty property2;
        private bool running2;
        private int curent;
        private UIElement element;

        public AnimationQueue(UIElement element , DependencyProperty property )
        {
            curent = -1;
            this.element = element;
            animation1 = new List<DoubleAnimation>();
            animation2 = new List<DoubleAnimation>();
            this.property1 = property;
        }

        public AnimationQueue(UIElement element, DependencyProperty property1 , DependencyProperty property2)
        {
            curent = -1;
            this.element = element;
            animation1 = new List<DoubleAnimation>();
            animation2 = new List<DoubleAnimation>();
            this.property1 = property1;
            this.property2 = property2;
        }

        public void queueAnimation(DoubleAnimation animation1, DoubleAnimation animation2)
        {

            animation1.Completed += (s, e) =>
            {
                running1 = false;
            };
            animation2.Completed += (s, e) =>
            {
                running2 = false;
            };

            this.animation1.Add(animation1);
            this.animation2.Add(animation2);


        }



        public void start(int i)
        {
            if (animation1.Count != animation2.Count)
                Console.WriteLine("Animation Queue not equal");
            else
            {
                if (i == animation1.Count)
                    Console.WriteLine("Animation finished");
                else if (i <= animation1.Count && i <= animation2.Count)
                {
                    element.BeginAnimation(property1, animation1[i]);
                    element.BeginAnimation(property2, animation2[i]);

                    if (running1 == false && running2 == false)
                    {
                        i++;
                        start(i);
                    }
                } 
            }
        }

        public void start()
        {
            curent = 0;
            element.BeginAnimation(property1, animation1[curent]);
            element.BeginAnimation(property2, animation2[curent]);

            if(running1 == false && running2 == false)
                start(curent++);
        }

    }`
```

In this class I add 2 animations for each point in the coordinate list . 1 to animate the x axis movement and 1 to anymate the y axis movement . The adding goes like this :

```
 public void StartCourse()
    {
        int i = 0;
        List<Point> coordinates = course.firstFuntion();
        while (coordinates.Count != i)
        {
            queue1.queueAnimation(new DoubleAnimation(coordinates[i].X, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))),
                                   new DoubleAnimation(coordinates[i].Y, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)))
                                 );
            i++;
        }
        queue1.start();

    }
```

My problem is , I believe , in the AnimationQueue.Start() method. The program stars the animation , however it only executes the first animation . After that it stops . I tried to make use of the animation.Completed Event Handler but to no success.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [DoubleAnimationUsingPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimationusingpath(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Or probably a [PointAnimationUsingPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.pointanimationusingpath(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: For my purpose I think that will do it , I am implementing it now , however I would still like to know how I could have done this with the class I made

Comment: Why cannot you use Queue<DoubleAnimation> instead of List<DoubleAnimation>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeginAnimation starts animation asynchrously. I suppose this may help:

```
private class AnimationQueue
{
    private List<DoubleAnimation> animation1 ;
    private DependencyProperty property1;
    private bool running1;
    private List<DoubleAnimation> animation2;
    private DependencyProperty property2;
    private bool running2;
    private int curent;
    private UIElement element;

    public AnimationQueue(UIElement element , DependencyProperty property )
    {
        curent = -1;
        this.element = element;
        animation1 = new List<DoubleAnimation>();
        animation2 = new List<DoubleAnimation>();
        this.property1 = property;
    }

    public AnimationQueue(UIElement element, DependencyProperty property1 , DependencyProperty property2)
    {
        curent = -1;
        this.element = element;
        animation1 = new List<DoubleAnimation>();
        animation2 = new List<DoubleAnimation>();
        this.property1 = property1;
        this.property2 = property2;
    }

    public void queueAnimation(DoubleAnimation animation1, DoubleAnimation animation2)
    {
        this.animation1.Add(animation1);
        this.animation2.Add(animation2);

        animation1.Completed += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (this.animation1.Contains(animation1))
            {
                int index1 = this.animation1.IndexOf(animation1);
                if (index1 + 1 < this.animation1.Count)
                {
                    element.BeginAnimation(property1, animation1[index1 + 1]);
                }
            }
        };
        animation2.Completed += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (this.animation2.Contains(animation2))
            {
                int index2 = this.animation2.IndexOf(animation2);
                if (index2 + 1 < this.animation2.Count)
                {
                    element.BeginAnimation(property2, animation2[index2 + 1]);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public void start()
    {
        curent = 0;
        element.BeginAnimation(property1, animation1[curent]);
        element.BeginAnimation(property2, animation2[curent]);
    }
}`
```

Comment: It works but odly enough it only moves the ellipse on the Y axis .

Comment: Perhaps it appears because of rest of code that is not in your question. There is no even queue1 declaration. You could either share your code or add it to your question

Comment: It was a missing } , so the method jumped over a call for the scond animation . It works now.